# Change text color of UILabel inside Custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

I have been trying to change the Text Color of a `UILabel` inside a Custom cell in `UICollectionView`. Currently I am using following code which allows me to change background color of the `Cell` but I only need to change the text color:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {

    //Change background color of selected Cell

    let selectedCell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 102/256, green: 255/256, blue: 255/256, alpha: 0.66)

    }


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {

    //Set background color of selected Cell to Clear Color 

    let cellToDeselect:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!

    cellToDeselect.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    }
```

I have seen few apps in which a hair line kind of thing keeps moving under selected cell. Anyone knows how to implement that as well?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its a custom Cell you will need to add a label to your custom UICollectionViewCell

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let label: UILabel! = nil

}
```

Then, in selectItemAtIndexPath:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let selectedCell: CustomCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomCell
    selectedCell.label.textColor = UIColor(red: 102/256, green: 255/256, blue: 255/256, alpha: 0.66)

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: You're welcome. If this was helpful please select it as the answer and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

```
theLableYouWantToChangeColor.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

As you say custom `UICollectionViewCell`, you have to create a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and add a `UILabel` inside.

Comment: Exactly this is what I have done:

class SliderCustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var sliderCellLabel: UILabel!
}

Comment: Now how do I make it visible in another class function. To be specific in didSelect and deSelect methods? and finally change color of text...?

Comment: Use it at cellforItems.... when you create the cell. I don't understand what do you mena by "Now how do I make it visible in another class function"

Comment: I meant I am able to use this label in cellForItemAtIndexPath() but if I want to use in it in other methods like didSelectItemAtIndexPath() and didDeselectItemAtIndexPath(). How do I do it? Because code for changing text color of selected cell label has to go in these methods. I hope its clear now. Else please feel free to ping again.

Comment: In short, please let me know the code for didSelectItemAtIndexPath() and didDeselectItemAtIndexPath() for changing text color of label in Custom UICollectionViewCell class.

Answer (score 0):

You should have cell reference and make that label property accessible from other class and access and change that Or pass the color object to cell and change it there only.
Other checks: Reference should not be nil, If IBOutlet then it should be connected.